# $L^1$ limit of indicator functions must be an indicator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve this question from Folland's book:
Assume $\mu(E_n)<\infty$ and $\chi_{E_n}\to f$ in $L^1$, so $f=\chi_E$ a.e, for some $E$.

I don't have much clue.. I think that $E$ should be $\limsup E_n$ but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WLOG, you may assume it is a probability measure and $X_{E_n}\rightarrow f \;\text{in}\;L_1$ implies $X_{E_n}$ converges to $f$ in probability which further implies that exists a subsequence $X_{E_{n_k}} $ converges to $f$ almost sure. Now , since $X_{E_{n_k}}$ is only zero and one, this means $f$ can only take value 0-1, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix any $k>0$, and consider the set
$$
A_k=\{x\colon |f(x)|>\frac{1}{k},|f(x)-1|>\frac{1}{k}\}.
$$
Observe that $$\int|f-\chi_{E_n}|\geq \int_{A_k}|f-\chi_{E_n}|\geq \frac{\mu(A_k)}{k}.$$
Since $\chi_{E_n}\to f$ in $L^1$, it follows that $\mu(A_k)=0$.

Let $A=\{x\colon f(x)\not=0,1\}$ and observe that $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$. By countable subbaditivity, it follows that $\mu(A)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)=0$. Hence $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ almost surely, as desired.

Comment: By the way, if you want to locate $E$ to show it is measurable, just observe that $E=f^{-1}(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\{x: \text{dist}(f(x), \{0,1\}) > \epsilon\}$ has measure $\eta > 0$, then
$\|f  - \chi_{E_n}\|_1 \ge \ldots$.