# Limit of a sequence of indicators function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am trying to prove or disprove this statement :

For $\phi$ a finite nonnegative measure on $[0,1]$ and $\left(\mathbf A_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$, there is a subsequence $\left(n_k\right)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ and a subset $\mathbf A \subset [0,1]$ such that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} \left|1_{\mathbf A_{n_k}}(x) - 1_{\mathbf A}(x)\right|\mathrm d \phi(x) = 0.$$

I am struggling with proving this statement, can any one help me to do it?

Comment: What is $\phi$? is it identified with a measure $\phi(x)dx$..if so,is this measure finite?

Comment: @MariosGretsas $\phi$ is a finite nonnegative measure on $[0,1]$

Comment: see that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155619/l1-limit-of-indicator-functions-must-be-an-indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Let $\phi = \operatorname{Leb}$ be the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0, 1]$ and consider

$$\mathbf{A}_{n} = \{x \in [0,1] : \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 2)} \}.$$

If $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}_{n_k}} \to \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}}$ in $L^1$ for some subsequence $(n_k)$ and a measurable set $\mathbf{A}$, then for any $f \in C_{b}([0,1])$ we have

$$ \int f(x) \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}_{n_k}} \, \mathrm{d}\phi
\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} \int f(x) \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}} \, \mathrm{d}\phi = \int_{\mathbf{A}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

On the other hand, we can easily check that

$$ \int f(x) \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}_{n}} \, \mathrm{d}\phi
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2} \int_{[0, 1]} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Now argue that there is no such $\mathbf{A}$ satisfying

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{[0, 1]} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbf{A}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \forall f \in C_b([0,1]). $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint, I assume that it is clear that the statement is false.